# Laravel 5: HTML with variables from DB for Mailable class

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

So I need to store my blade email templates in database.
And now I am having problem to use db content with view, because dynamic informations are not rendered.

Here is the code to elaborate a bit more problem which I am facing:

**Mailable class:**

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\User;

class activateUser extends Mailable
{

    public $html;
    public $user;

    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        //this actually is much longer text coming from the DB - basicly coopied blade email template into the db
        $this->html = 'Hi {{ $user->first_name }},<br /><br /> Your profile on our site has been activated.<br /><br />';
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.activateUser')->subject('Your account is activated');
    }
}
```

Then the view **emails.activateUser.blade.php** looks like this:

```
{{ $html }}
```

And Inside of **my controller** I am calling this:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new activateUser($user));
```

Problem is that actual username of the user will not be printed in the email and {{ }} will stay as well in email content.

Any ideas how to solve this, since my email template content needs to come from DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Blade template compiler to compile a string:

```
public function compileBladeString(string $template, $data = []): string
{
    $bladeCompiler = app('blade.compiler');

    ob_start() && extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);
    eval('?>' . $bladeCompiler->compileString($template));
    $compiled = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $compiled;
}
```

You can then simply invoke this method with a string containing your template from the database.

Comment: but here extract doesn't expect string (string is coming from db) - it expects array. Workaround for that ?

Comment: @Splendid I'm sorry, I must have made a mistake when copying the final code from the IDE. Fixed the script. `$data` is an additional parameter to pass variables. This means `$template` is a blade template in string form, for example `$template = '<h1>{{ $title }}</h1>'` and `$data` contains the necessary variables like `$data = ['title' => 'Hello World!']`. Calling the function is similar to calling `view('welcome', ['title' => 'Hello World!'])`, except that it does take the template itself as first parameter and not the name of the template file.